# Unable to update custom column value of sales_order via Rest API

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, custom-attributes, webapi

I want to trace records of all the completed orders which has been received from my Magento store to my ERP store through Rest API. I have created custom column through SQL query in `sales_order` so that I can get all those orders whose custom order value is set to 0 (default value).

I am using this API

`index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=custom_attribute&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1`

to get all the records of matching custom column value which is working perfect. However I need an API through which I can update the custom column value to 1 once I receive that order.

Is there any API available through which I can able to update the custom column value by order id?

Comment: I came to know there is this API with PUT method
index.php/rest/V1/orders/1
through which i can update the column data by passing entity[custom-attribute] = 0 but its throughing the unknown setter and getter error even after i have created the set and get method for this attribute in both controller and Model of OrderrepositoryInterface and orderInterface

Comment: Now its throwing this exception even after creating custom order attribute setter and getter method on orderinterface

{
"message": "Class 0 does not exist",
"code": -1,
"trace": "#0 /var/www/html/vangsgaards/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(148): ReflectionClass->__construct('0') #1 /var/www/html/vangsgaards/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(322): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('0', Array) #2 /var/www/html/vangsgaards/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(175)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind just found out the answer by myself. Magento2 Update Order attributes API index.php/rest/V1/orders/:orderid does not allow to update custom order attributes. So i have created my own custom API to cater my requirement